# Execute method is not calling in controller Magento 2

Tags: magento2, controllers, newsletter

I am facing issue with newsletter.
it suppose to subscribe user in newsletter and send them email
which seems not working

**execute method is not even calling. on direct accessing the url or using subscribe button**

**Please take a look & share your thoughts why its not working.**

**Thankyou**

I click a button on frontend it send post request to

```
$this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new', ['_secure' => true]);
```

**Default.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Rokanthemes\Themeoption\Block\Newsletterpopup" name="newsletter_popup" template="newsletterpopup.phtml" after="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

**phtml file**

```
<?php if($block->getConfig('enable') > 0){ ?>
     <!--style>
            #newsletter_pop_up{max-height: 100%;}
            #newsletter_pop_up #recaptcha1 {padding-top: 5px;}
     </style-->
<div id="newsletter_pop_up" class="newsletterpopup">
    <div href="javascript: void(0);" class="btn-close newletter_popup_close"><span></span></div>
    <div class="row border">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="content-popup"><?php echo $block->getConfig('content');?>
                <form class="form subscribe"
                    novalidate
                    action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormActionUrl()) ?>"
                    method="post"
                    data-mage-init='{"validation": {"errorClass": "mage-error"}}'
                    id="newsletter-validate-detail">
                    <div class="field newsletter">
                        <div class="control">
                            <div class="discount-text">
                                <h1>SAVE 10% ON YOUR FIRST ORDER</h1>
                                <p>Subscribe Now & Get a Free Coupon Code. The Code will be emailed to your provided Email Address.</p>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" name="username" id="news-user" placeholder="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Enter your Your Name') ?>">
                            <input name="email" type="email" id="newsletter-popup"
                                        placeholder="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Enter your email address') ?>"
                                        data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="actions">
                        <button class="action subscribe primary" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Subscribe Now') ?>" type="submit">
                            <span><?php echo __('Subscribe Now'); ?></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="subscribe-bottom">
                        <p>Not Valid With Any other Offer</p>
                        <!-- <input type="checkbox" id="newsletter_popup_dont_show_again">
                        <label for="newsletter_popup_dont_show_again"><?php //echo __("Do not show this popup again")?></label> -->
                    </div>
                </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
        /**
         *
         * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
         * See COPYING.txt for license details.
         */
        
        namespace Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber;
        
        use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface as CustomerAccountManagement;
        use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
        use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
        use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
        use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
        use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
        use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
        use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
        use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
        use Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress as EmailValidator;
        use Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber as SubscriberController;
        use Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber;
        use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
        use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
        use Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory;
        
        /**
         * New newsletter subscription action
         *
         * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
         */
        class NewAction extends SubscriberController implements HttpPostActionInterface
        {
            /**
             * @var CustomerAccountManagement
             */
            protected $customerAccountManagement;
        
            /**
             * @var EmailValidator
             */
            private $emailValidator;
        
            /**
             * Initialize dependencies.
             *
             * @param Context $context
             * @param SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory
             * @param Session $customerSession
             * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
             * @param CustomerUrl $customerUrl
             * @param CustomerAccountManagement $customerAccountManagement
             * @param EmailValidator $emailValidator
             */
            public function __construct(
                Context $context,
                SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
                Session $customerSession,
                StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
                CustomerUrl $customerUrl,
                CustomerAccountManagement $customerAccountManagement,
                EmailValidator $emailValidator = null
            ) {
                $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
                $this->emailValidator = $emailValidator ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(EmailValidator::class);
                parent::__construct(
                    $context,
                    $subscriberFactory,
                    $customerSession,
                    $storeManager,
                    $customerUrl
                );
            }
        
            /**
             * Validates that the email address isn't being used by a different account.
             *
             * @param string $email
             * @throws LocalizedException
             * @return void
             */
            protected function validateEmailAvailable($email)
            {
                $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
                if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()
                    && ($this->_customerSession->getCustomerDataObject()->getEmail() !== $email
                    && !$this->customerAccountManagement->isEmailAvailable($email, $websiteId))
                ) {
                    throw new LocalizedException(
                        __('This email address is already assigned to another user.')
                    );
                }
            }
        
            /**
             * Validates that if the current user is a guest, that they can subscribe to a newsletter.
             *
             * @throws LocalizedException
             * @return void
             */
            protected function validateGuestSubscription()
            {
                if ($this->_objectManager->get(ScopeConfigInterface::class)
                        ->getValue(
                            Subscriber::XML_PATH_ALLOW_GUEST_SUBSCRIBE_FLAG,
                            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                        ) != 1
                    && !$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()
                ) {
                    throw new LocalizedException(
                        __(
                            'Sorry, but the administrator denied subscription for guests. Please <a href="%1">register</a>.',
                            $this->_customerUrl->getRegisterUrl()
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
        
            /**
             * Validates the format of the email address
             *
             * @param string $email
             * @throws LocalizedException
             * @return void
             */
            protected function validateEmailFormat($email)
            {
                if (!$this->emailValidator->isValid($email)) {
                    throw new LocalizedException(__('Please enter a valid email address.'));
                }
            }
        
            /**
             * New subscription action
             *
             * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
             */
            public function execute()
            {
                $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
                $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
                $logger->addWriter($writer);
                $logger->info('Your text message');
                if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('email')) {
                    $email = (string)$this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
        
                    try {
                        $this->validateEmailFormat($email);
                        $this->validateGuestSubscription();
                        $this->validateEmailAvailable($email);
        
                        $subscriber = $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->loadByEmail($email);
                        if ($subscriber->getId()
                            && (int) $subscriber->getSubscriberStatus() === Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED
                        ) {
                            throw new LocalizedException(
                                __('This email address is already subscribed.')
                            );
                        }
        
                        $status = (int) $this->_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($email);
                        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($this->getSuccessMessage($status));
                    } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Something went wrong with the subscription.'));
                    }
                }
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $redirect */
                $redirect = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
                $redirectUrl = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl();
                return $redirect->setUrl($redirectUrl);
            }
        
            /**
             * Get success message
             *
             * @param int $status
             * @return Phrase
             */
            private function getSuccessMessage(int $status): Phrase
            {
                if ($status === Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
                    return __('The confirmation request has been sent.');
                }
        
                return __('Thank you for your subscription.');
            }
        }
```

Comment: any thoughts ??

Comment: what you getting on direct controller hit ? Add your routes.xml in question.

Comment: Hello Pawan i have updated question

Comment: I get nothing in response as page gets redirected to self with Status Code: 302. could you please help debugging it ?

Comment: any thoughts ??

Comment: any thoughts ??

Comment: Hi amit, i found that issue is due to mageplaza google recaptcha.

Answer (score 1):

**`newsletter/subscriber/new`** does not hit because of Newsletter module is **disabled from Magento admin**.

Goto Admin navigate to  `Store -> Configuration -> Customers -> Newsletter -> General Options` and here make `Enabled` = Yes to resolve the issue.

If you check `vendor/magento/module-newsletter/etc/frontend/events.xml` and here you can `controller_action_predispatch_newsletter` event fire an observer `\Magento\Newsletter\Observer\PredispatchNewsletterObserver::execute` where url going to Default no route instead of hitting `\Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction::execute`.

Also note that `new` Action is implementing `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface` so only post request support for this url, If you are trying to access via GET then it wil be 404.

Comment: Hello Amit, thanks for the answer. i want to let you know that its Enabled from backend. I have a custom form that has form action as $this->getUrl('newsletter/subscriber/new', ['_secure' => true]); this calls the above controller but when i add log or use echo exit in it. i dont see any changes, That simply means execute method is not calling

Comment: Cany you please take a look at the file above & advise where i can debug ?

Comment: Are you using POST method? means <form action` should `post`?

Comment: yes sir its a post method

Comment: i have updated & added called phtml code

Comment: is works with default field for newsletter , its just that when called controller from custom form its not calling execute.

Comment: You'll be able to catch the issue now, i have added while code.

Comment: is google Recaptcha opened at your system?

Comment: no its not......

Comment: It seems there is some issue with either js used by popup or the request method.

I have checked by replacing the popup form content with default newsletter form(html), it calls the controller.

But with current form it does not work.

Comment: Any thoughts? It seems like js issue. The identifier used with js in order to appear html as popup creates issue, if i change the identifier it works. Controller  called.

Answer (score -1):

In Magento 2, the controller class does not need to add the "Action" suffix. You have defined the controller class as:

```
class NewAction
```

which should be like:

```
class New
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: shall i change file name too ?

Comment: i am have removed redirection code from the execute method though its still redirect, how can i stop it ? Thankyou

Comment: Its not working